# Use the contents of a string variable as a condition for an if statement?

Tags: vb.net

Suppose I want to use an If statement, but I won't know until run-time what the actual condition of the If statement will be. Is there a way to do this by passing the condition as the contents of a string? As an example of the kind of thing I'm looking to acheive, consider the following bit of code;

```
Dim a as Integer = 1
Dim b as Integer = 2
Dim ConditionString As String = "<"

    If a ConditionString b Then
            ...
    End If
```

Mainly what I'm looking for is some way to leave the actual condition undefined until run-time. The reason I want to do this is because I need to have a set of threshold conditions in a database including not just the numeric values themselves, but also comparison operations. I might want to have something that amounts to "> 3.2 And < 5.6". As numbers are pulled in from data, the comparison operations need to be applied to the data depending on various conditions. Also, the database would be changed from time-to-time.

Comment: Would you provide some further examples of definite, likely, or even possible values of `ConditionString` ("the comparison operations")? That would help determine which answers are most appropriate.

Comment: After further consideration, I flagged this to be closed. The direct answer to your question is "No, you can't evaluate a string as an expression in VB.NET.". But as the varied answers indicate, there's probably lots of different ways to implement the functionality you're hinting at. If you can, edit your question to be clearer as to what you're asking.

Comment: `something that amounts to "> 3.2 And < 5.6"` that is a horrible idea.  there is at least 2 distinct pieces of data there, gluing them together just to later parse them is a bad idea.  Simple `Min` and `Max`values would work for this, and with additional qualifiers could be more expansive.

Comment: Kenny, I think my statement "Mainly what I'm looking for is some way to leave the actual condition undefined until run-time." sums it up. The details of the actual conditional statements and threshold values isn't particularly important. I didn't expect a solution to be built into .NET. Konrad's solution below looks like a pretty good alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such cases I love to use [`NCalc`](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) library, it has everything you need - it parses simple expressions (including logical and relational). Here is an example of it in C#:

```
var expr = new Expression("[X] > 3.2 and [X] < 5.6");
expr.Parameters["X"] = 10.0;
if (expr.Evaluate())
{
   // ...
}
```

and VB.NET:

```
Dim expr As var = New Expression("[X] > 3.2 and [X] < 5.6")
expr.Parameters("X") = 10
If expr.Evaluate Then
    ' ...
End If
```

Comment: That seems like killing a fly with a bazooka given the dearth of "operations" in the original question, but it's pretty cool nonetheless!

Comment: @KennyEvitt, I absolutely disagree. Killing a fly with a bazooka would be writing such parser from scratch. Notice OP wants to parse expressions like `"> 3.2 And < 5.6"`.

Comment: Based on the example code in the question, the OP simply needs to evaluate two integers with a variable operator.

Comment: That is how I interpreted the question because `something that amounts to "> 3.2 And < 5.6"` was less clear then the earlier description.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to check it out. So far it looks like the closest to what I'm looking for because I can just combine the threshold numbers and the comparison operators in a single string in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can store a map of `String` to `Func(Of Integer, Integer, Boolean)` keyed by the strings "<", ">", "==", and so on, and take addresses of the functions that implement those conditions. For example:

```
Function LessThan(Integer a, Integer b) As Boolean
    Return a < b
End Function

Dim Comparisons As New Map(Of String, Func(Of Integer, Integer, Boolean))
Comparisons.Add("<", AddressOf LessThan)
```

And then you can call it as such:

```
Dim a as Integer = 1
Dim b as Integer = 2
Dim ConditionString As String = "<"

If Comparisons(ConditionString)(a, b) Then
```

Comment: I wonder how many different ways there are of composing this kind of indirection?

Answer (score 0):

There are only a few possible conditions so I would just use a Select..Case statement:

```
    Select Case ConditionString
        Case "<"

        Case ">"

        'etc.
        Case Else

    End Select
```

Otherwise, you cannot (simply) convert a string "<" to an operator.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a 'code', mapping some kind of value that you can store in a database to the various kinds of "conditions" you wish to test. Instead of a string, I'd suggest using an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h84wky1.aspx):

```
Enum ConditionEnum
    LessThan
    GreaterThan
    Equal
    SomeOtherVeryComplicatedBinaryFunction
End Enum
```

And then define a method that evaluates the condition along with the two arguments:

```
Public Sub EvaluateConditionWithArguments(ConditionEnum condition, Integer a, Integer b) As Boolean

    EvaluateConditionWithArguments = False

    Select Case condition
        Case ConditionEnum.LessThan
            If a < b Then
                EvaluateConditionWithArguments = True
            End If
        ...
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: If I keep the threshold values separate from the comparison operator(s), each stored in the database, then I can see how this and the answer directly above would work. But if I want to keep them as a single string I would have to do some parsing, or use the first answer above.

Comment: @timothyjb, yes, that's true. But it wasn't clear from your original question exactly what you wanted or needed to do. Now it's clear that you don't really have a clear *and concise* question that fits the format of this site. But there's lots of great suggestions in the answers that should help anyways!